# I’d never have guessed that they were married

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider these sentences, please:

1. *Looking at her now you’d never guess she **had been** so upset.*

Can I use "has been" or "was" in place of "had been" in the sentence above?

2. *I’d never have guessed that they **were** married.*

Are they still married or is the sentence talking about them being married in the past? Can I use "had been" in place of "were" in sentence 2)?

Comment: Your first example requires a ***past tense narrative context*** to justify using *Past **Perfect*** (to refer to some time ***earlier*** than the "narrative reference time". The second example is normal English "backshifting", which in and of itself implies nothing about whether the situation being referenced is Past or Present. So *I didn't know you had 'flu* works fine regardless of whether the addressee ***is currently*** or ***was*** sick.

Comment: (1) '[Her son was out of work for years and then he got this wonderful position.] She had been so upset. You would never guess this fact, looking at her now.' // (1') '[Until quite recently, her son was out of work.] She has been so upset. You would never guess this fact, looking at her now.' _So either is licensed, given licensing context._ //// (2a) Indeterminate. / (2a') 'are' (the power of the indicative!) or 'were once' disambiguate. // (2b) Again, context licenses / informs.

Comment: Do we use **subjunctive or unreal past** tense verbs in the "that-clauses" of "*You would never guess/would never have guessed that...*" and "*You would/might think that...*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subject of sentence 1. *has been* upset in the recent past but is not upset at the time of writing.

Sentence 2. would be understood to mean that the couple are currently married. Using *had been* would require something more.

*I'd never have guessed that they had been married for so long.*

Or, if they are no longer married:

*I'd never have guessed that they had once been married.*

Comment: What is the difference between these? "*I would never guess they **are** married*" and "*I would never guess they **were** married*".

Comment: I think _were_ is the standard form - it goes with the conditional tense "[If you had not told me] I would never have guessed [that it was true]." However, people sometimes use the present tense because they are speaking of something that is true at the present time.

Comment: Thanks. But my question in the comments was about "I'd never guess that...".

Comment: Then why did you highlight **are** and **were**? Again, I think _would never have guessed_ is the standard form (you now know the true facts, so you no longer need to guess), and _would never guess_ is a nonstandard variant.